# Can open-uri be used across rack applications?

Tags: sinatra, rack, open-uri, grape-api

Currently I have a Sinatra web app & a Grape API, the idea being to implement the Sinatra app in such a way that the web app is just another API consumer.

In my config.ru I have this:

```
run Rack::Cascade.new [API, Application]
```

`API` is the Grape app & `Application` is the Sinatra app. I am using open-uri to try to grab the JSON from the Grape api in a Sinatra route. I am using thin. *I am omitting the /uri after the port number for ease of reading, the Grape & Sinatra apps work independently, I will explain further in a moment*

`open("http://localhost")` returns:

```
#<StringIO:0x007fbeab1b2e68
@base_uri=#<URI::HTTP:0x007fbeab1d47e8 URL:http://localhost>,
@meta=
 {"content-type"=>"text/html; charset=utf8",
  "x-pow-template"=>"welcome",
  "date"=>"Fri, 06 Sep 2013 07:29:15 GMT",
  "connection"=>"keep-alive",
  "transfer-encoding"=>"chunked"},
@status=["200", "OK"]>
```

However, if I `open("http://localhost:9292")` the application hangs. I feel like maybe something is blocking I/O, like perhaps its waiting for itself to connect to itself but I am not sure enough of whats going on *under the hood* to really be sure.

If I point pow at it, spin it up at `project.dev` & then spin it up with `rackup` so I have two instances I can use `open("http://project.dev/what/ever/url/i_need")` & it works like a charm. So the problem seems to be somewhere in pointing open-uri at itself... I think...

Is this because of the `Rack::Cascade`? is this a problem with `thin`? or maybe the with `open-uri`? Is this just completely the wrong way to approach this problem?

I am open to just about any solution however I would prefer to keep it as simple as possible, with minimal external requires as I intent to use this pattern frequently.

Let me know if any additional information is required & I will do my best to provide it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that sinatra and open-uri step over each other, as I faced the same issue with sinatra 1.4.4 using different servers (puma, webrick, thin).

My solution was to switch to `curb` and this solved the problem.